# Automatically close netrw after opening a file

Tags: netrw

I would like to automatically close the netrw window when I open a file. I've found a similar question ([NERDTree How to open a file and automatically close the explorer buffer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/nerdtree-how-to-open-a-file-and-automatically-close-the-explorer-buffer)), but it refers to NERDTree - not netrw.

This is my `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
set autochdir
map <C-E> :Lexplore<CR>
```

Edit:
This works when using `:Explore`, but in my case, I'm trying to make it work when I use `:Lexplore`

Comment: Isn't that what happens by default? E.g. I run `:Explore`, the netrw Directory Listing comes up in the current buffer, I select a file pressing `<Enter>` and that file is opened in the current window (and netrw is closed)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt when you use :Explore - yes, but I'm using :Lexplore (I don't like when it covers everything)

Comment: That is an information, that you should have shared in your question.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt My apologies, I assumed it would be obvious from my .vimrc file.

Comment: Did you find a solution @GiladNovik?

Comment: As indicated in another comment, `:Lex` is a persistent browser (stays open until manually closed): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766814/close-netrw-explorer-after-opening-a-new-file ... I have this in my `~/.vimrc` : `noremap <silent> <leader>l :Lex<CR>` ("leader elle")

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem comes from the following line of your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
```

From the doc [`:h g:netrw_browse_split`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#g%3anetrw_browse_split)
you can read:

```
  *g:netrw_browse_split*    when browsing, <cr> will open the file by:
                =0: re-using the same window  (default)
                =1: horizontally splitting the window first
                =2: vertically   splitting the window first
                =3: open file in new tab
                =4: act like "P" (ie. open previous window)
```

So this should solve your problem:

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 0
```

---

Otherwise I think you may be able to adapt the autocommand solution from the question you linked since netrw buffers has a filetype set to `netrw`.

Comment: I've just tried to change it to 0 - it still opens in the same window, but netrw still stays open after.

Comment: @GiladNovik I just read your comment answering to ChristianBrabandt, the doc also says `This option does not affect :Lexplore windows.` so indeed that might not be a solution for you.

Comment: I'm unsure what the OP means but if you want to close netrw if it's the last buffer, e.g. when you are exiting this file you opened, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012106/automatically-quit-vim-if-netrw-is-last-and-only-buffer